# Can a mysql database has foreign key that refer to tables in another db server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, hibernate

Say I have two tables, Address and Person, which resides on two totally separate servers. I want to refer to Address in Person by a foreign key.

I want to put them in separate servers, because they are with the databases that perform jobs closer to each of them. e.g. the DB person resides in may define a lot of tables that relate to Person, but none of them except Person relate to Address, and vice versa. Failing of the server Person resides on will have no impact on the Address's server, unless the foreign key is involved in the action.

If this makes sense, how can I do that in mysql? And how can I do that in java using hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can have trigger to ensure foreign key constraint.